# cluster google maps markers on ios with swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-ios-utils

I have to develop an app that uses google-maps and it has many markers on the map. one of the requirement is to cluster these markers when the user zooms out.

I know this question has been asked before, but those questions are old and with objective-c(with which I have no experience at all). The language that I am using is swift and I was wandering if a simpler solution has been made available since 2013 from when those questions have been asked.

Thank you!

Comment: I found tons of [library](https://github.com/choefele/CCHMapClusterController) about `cluster google maps` in objective-c also and can not find the swift either, but there is a convertor that you can try [here](http://objectivec2swift.net/#/about) it will give you some idea about `cluster google maps` in swift.

Answer (score 0):

There is an SDK now. It has a static library so it won't work with use_frameworks - you can manually add it to your project following these instruction [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md).

Comment: This answer might be great, by it's far better to explain a bit about the sdk\tool\off-site resource you link to. Perhaps an example on how to use it etc. Include the important and relevant parts from the sdk in your answer.